# How to set width of form_tag with Bootstrap in Rails 4.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

The following  html: {} sets view width for `form_for`. However it does not work the same for `form_tag` and the tag widths are not even and narrow:

```
<%= form_tag my_url, :method => :get, html: { class: 'form-horizontal col-sm-10'},
    wrapper: :horizontal_form,
    wrapper_mappings: {
    check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :horizontal_file_input,
    boolean: :horizontal_boolean } do  %>
               ...
 <% end %>
```

There is no html: option for `form_tag` and we suspect it may not be the right format for setting the width with bootstrap. What's the right option to set width with bootstrap?

Comment: Try just this (without `html:`): `<%= form_tag my_url, :method => :get, class: 'form-horizontal col-sm-10'`. see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution we found:

```
<%= form_tag my_url, :method => :get, class: 'form-horizontal' do  %>
   #wrap each tag inside 'form-control', add 'control-label' to label and 'form-control' to tag.         ...
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-4"> 
         <%= label_tag 'My Label' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= date_field_tag 'My Date', nil, placeholder: Date.today.to_s, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is how the form look like:
[image]

Here is link on W3school about `Bootstrap` form: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

`html` option is avaiable for [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) but NOT for [form_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag).

To fix your issue, replace:

```
<%= form_tag my_url, :method => :get, html: { class: 'form-horizontal col-sm-10'}
```

with:

```
<%= form_tag my_url, :method => :get, class: 'form-horizontal col-sm-10'
```

Comment: The change has no effect on width. Also tried to removed all other options. Same width unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

To your point: `the right format for setting the width with bootstrap.`

Bootstrap is expecting this type of  structure:

```
     <div class="row"> 
       ...
      <%= form_tag(form_tag my_url, :method => :get, :class => "form-group") do %>
          <div class="input-group">
               Fields here...          
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <%= button_tag  name: nil, class: "btn btn-default", type: "submit" do %>            
                <% end %>
              </span> <!-- -btn -->
        </div> <!-- "input-group" --> 

    <% end %> <!-- form -->

   </div> <!-- row -->
```

**Horizontal forms**

A quick addition about horizontal forms, like those for logging in in a header

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="row">
    ...
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <span class="input-group-addon input-group-xs" id="basic-addon1">
                <%= f.button :submit, t('.login'), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default nudge_down_6" %></span>
            <span class="input-group-addon input-group-xs" id="basic-addon1">
                <%= f.input :email,  class: 'form-control input-group-xs nudge_down_6', required: false %></span>
            <span class="input-group-addon input-group-xs" id="basic-addon1">
                <%= f.input :password,  class: 'form-control input-group-xs nudge_down_6', required: false %></span>
        </div>
```

Let me know if this snippet helps and I can follow up with more, if needed.

**Debug note**

The web browser console shows all and tells all. You can inspect each rendered HTML element and see which is setting the width that you want to change then override it. But if you use Bootstrap with the structure it specifies for CSS tags, then override tweaking should be minimal.

Comment: Hi, tried :class => "form-group" in form_tag and no luck. We would like to set make the width wider with for_tag option. Thanks.

Comment: You have top use the entire structure of CSS tags, div, not just a single tag. That's the only way you can get Bootstrap to work as advertised. Once you get it working you can try pulling tags out until it stops working, then you know those are the essential elements. Good luck.